# Unable to include a file in child theme

Tags: xampp

I am using the following code in functions.php of the child theme to include a file

```
require_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/functions/taxonomy-images.php');
```

But i get these warnings and fatal error

```
Warning: require_once(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\yakoo\wp-content\themes\listify-child\functions.php on line 68

Warning: require_once(http://localhost/yakoo/wp-content/themes/listify-child/functions/taxonomy-images.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in C:\xampp\htdocs\yakoo\wp-content\themes\listify-child\functions.php on line 68

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost/yakoo/wp-content/themes/listify-child/functions/taxonomy-images.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\yakoo\wp-content\themes\listify-child\functions.php on line 68
```

No idea what s going wrong.

Please help

Comment: Looks like a server configuration error. Can you post this question on the xampp forums as localized errors are off topic here.

Comment: okayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 2):

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

Note that this returns a properly-formed URI; in other words, it will be a web-address (starting with http:// or https:// for SSL). As such, it is most appropriately used for links, referencing additional stylesheets, or probably most commonly, images.

```
get_stylesheet_directory()
```

Retrieve stylesheet directory Path for the current theme/child theme.
**Note**: Does not contain a trailing slash.
Returns an absolute server path (eg: /home/user/public_html/wp-content/themes/my_theme), not a URI.

So I guess this

```
require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/functions/taxonomy-images.php' );
```

should be fine.

Comment: Now it doesn't give error but instead there is ?> in its place. So i guess still its not working

Comment: @amritanshu what do you mean?

Comment: I mean there is this symbol ?> at the top of the page

Comment: I have removed <?php & ?> from the answer.

Comment: :)  of course i removed it already...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, It works:

```
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/functions/taxonomy-images.php';
```

Comment: You don't need dirname if you replace FILE with DIR.